# How can i generate parcel extracts on demand through a webservice

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-9.3, sql-server, reports

Ok, i need to generate parcel extract documents on demand. The backend is Arcgis 9.3.1 on SQL server 2008. I would like to build a webservice (C# .Net) on the server that generates these extracts. My experience is writing with arcobjects to extend Arcmap. But now i just want to access the data and generate without this UI.  What are the options i have? Any suggestions would be great. (p.s. it is not necessary to stick to .NET) I only need some advice or direction. I'll try to describe my problem in general. The extracts will be requested over the internet. So the only thing the system should do is returning an jpg or pdf. That's all. The problem i have now is that i don't now how to do it. Any concept or advise would be great. Sorry if this is still to generic. I have to format the extract from a template so a grid and a north arrow is added. I know how to do this with arcobjects in arcmap but i don't know how to use arcobjects from a webservice and i even don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. It isn't really clear what you are asking here. Its hard to answer a generic question without specific details - after all, your options are whatever you choose to look at. What have you tried? What worked? What didn't work? It also might be useful to describe why you are trying to do things a particular way, to avoid suggestions that don't address your issues.

Comment: I only need some advice or direction. I'll try to describe my problem in general. The extracts will be requested over the internet. So the only thing the system should do is returning an jpg or pdf. That's all. The problem i have now is that i don't now how to do it. Any concept or advise would be great.    Sorry if this is still to generic. I have to format the extract from a template so a grid and a north arrow is added. I know how to do this with arcobjects in arcmap but i don't know how to use arcobjects from a webservice and i even don't know if this is possible.

Comment: This info should have gone into the original question, and it still can - just click edit below the question and update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to read up on SOAP ( http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/soap/whnjs.htm) and REST (http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/index.html)  services.

At 9.3.1 you could still use ArcObjects, but you had to duplicate all your code because the objects had to be created in a ServerContext.  But ArcObjects were still available.  I have since moved on to 10 and 10.1 so I can't find any legacy code to give you as a sample.

At 10.0 and above, ESRI has an ESRI.ArcGIS.SOESupport dll that lets you build Server Object Extensions using ArcObjects and you can reuse your ArcObject libraries directly.  10.1 even makes it easier and is worth the upgrade if you can do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links. Unfortunately i have to stick by 9.3.1 The organisation is in Africa and don't have money for a upgrade. If i do the rest/soap solution i don't know how to format the output. They would like to have a different grid, scale bar and north arrow based on the parcel size. Do you have any idea on how to do this?